# Dimension of open set in locally compact Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

Is the dimension of open set in a locally compact Hausdorff space same as the dimension of the space? I can only think of Euclidean space which must be same, however I cannot come up a counterexample.

**Edit**
By "dimension", I mean topological dimension, or the Lebesgue covering dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $X=[0,1]\vee [0,1]^2$, [the wedge sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedge_sum) of $[0,1]$ with $[0,1]^2$. For simplicity we glue at boundaries. Then $(0,1)$ is open in $X$ and so is $(0,1)^2$. And these are manifolds having dimension $1$ and $2$ respectively. And so at least one of them has to have the (Lebesgue covering) dimension different from $X$ (which is $2$ by the way).

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=\bigoplus_{n \in \Bbb N} \Bbb S^n$ be the disjoint sum of $n$-spheres. $X$ is infinite dimensional but no connected open subset is infinite-dimensional.

Comment: Henno, do you know of an example of a locally compact $T_2$ space $X$ for which there is an open subset $U\subseteq X$ with $\dim U>\dim X$? I don't know much dimension theory and have only a rather obscure (non ZFC) example.

Comment: @Tyrone no access to my dimension theory books, so I cannot easily check. There might be. With dimension theory it’s safest to stick to separable metric spaces.